# Not received success callback with android plaid sdk in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, onactivityresult, plaid

I implemented plaid sdk in my android app with version - 0.3.0

I not received success or any callback after click on last screen "Continue" button.

After click on "Continue", I got callback with onActivityResult() with resultCode=0 but not related to any Plaid Result code.

I created only one Activity as MainActivity and also use this as Redirected Activity.

===== AndroidManifest.xml =====

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

                <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:host="plaid-redirect"
                        android:scheme="plaidtestapp" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
<activity android:name="com.plaid.link.LinkActivity" />
```

===== MainActivity.kt =====

```
val intent = Intent(this, LinkActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra( Plaid.LINK_CONFIGURATION,
LinkConfiguration(
// required
clientName = "Plaid Test App",
products = listOf(PlaidProduct.TRANSACTIONS),
webviewRedirectUri = "plaidtestapp://plaid-redirect",
// optional
environment = PlaidEnvironment.SANDBOX, // Defaults to plaid options value if set or SANDBOX
language = Locale.ENGLISH.language, // Defaults to English
countryCodes = listOf(Locale.US.country), // Defaults to US
webhook = "https://requestb.in",
userEmailAddress = "{registered email id}",
userLegalName = "{registered email id}",
userPhoneNumber = "{phone number}") )
startActivityForResult(intent, LINK_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Reference Github Link
https://github.com/plaid/plaid-link-android

Thanks in Advance, Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

Its solved by updating plaid sdk version to 0.3.1

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.plaid.link:sdk-core:0.3.1'
}
```

On Plaid document site, they still keep the old version, Please update version to 0.3.1.

With new version it receiving all callbacks